# R Extract day from datetime

Tags: r, date, format, extract

Hi I need to remain only with the day of each date:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("2014-07-24 00:00:00", 
"2014-07-24 00:00:00", "2014-07-11", "2014-07-11" ,"2014-07-16" ,"2014-07-14"))
as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%d" )
```

I tried this:

```
df$dia<-as.Date(df$x, format="%d")
```

But I get a full date and different from the orginal.

I don't want to install another package to do this.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: `df$x <- as.Date(df$x)` ? Do you want the name of the day? `weekdays(df$x)` Do you want a numeric result?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: A date, by definition, is a year, month, and day. You need to provide more information for people to best help you. Some of the values of `df$x` have times. What timezone are they in? Are the times always `"00:00:00"`? If you just want the day as a string, you can use `format(as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%d")`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you looking for `format`?

```
format(as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d")
# [1] "24" "24" "11" "11" "16" "14"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your dates are always in the same position and format, you have another option with `substr()`.  The call below starts with the 9th position -- the start of the day -- and ends with the 10th -- the second number of the day.

```
substr(x = df$x, start = 9, stop = 10)
[1] "24" "24" "11" "11" "16" "14"
```

Comment: If somebody is looking for numeric or factor format with the same functionality, then simply use the type converter: as.numeric or as.factor.

Answer (score 2):

Since your result will no longer be a date anyway, you could use `gsub`

```
gsub("(.*)[-]", "", df$x)
# [1] "24" "24" "11" "11" "16" "14"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x), '-'), function(x) x[3])
[1] "24" "24" "11" "11" "16" "14"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the class of the variable to date type then try

```
df$dia <- format(df$x, "%d")
```

else, nest the format function within as.date function

Answer (score 0):

It's a function in [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/day.html)

```
library(lubridate)
day(date)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `weekdays(df$date)` to extract the day of the week from the date. Only make sure the column is of type `Date` or convert using `as.Date()`.