# Date to day and time

Tags: r, datetime

I have read a lot of blogs, but I cannot find the answer to my question:

I have a date `2020-25-02 17:45:03` and I would like to convert it to two columns day and time.

```
hello <- strptime(as.character("2020-25-02 17:42:03"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$day <- as.Date(hello, format = "%Y-%d-%m")
```

But I also would like `df$time`. Is it possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043627/r-extract-day-from-datetime

Comment: Thank you, I searched but I could not find the right comment.

Comment: Thank you. But actually it does not answer my question. This post is only to find the day, but I would like the time.

Comment: There's no built-in way to store parsed times without days in R. There are ones in the `hms` (newer) and `chron` (older) packages if you want, but often people just leave them as POSIXct timestamps if they do correspond to one particular time, which has useful side-effects like having timezone info attached.

Comment: Oh, and use `as.POSIXct()` instead of `strptime()`; the latter converts to POSIXlt instead of POSIXct. There are reasons, but the tl;dr is that POSIXct is the chosen standard.

Comment: And you can drop the `as.character()` if you like; it's already a character vector

Comment: And the format you're passing to `as.Date()` is wrong, since datetime classes are always `%Y-%m-%d`. It will be ignored because the object you're passing in is a classed timestamp, though, so it's mostly just misleading. And sorry for all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
 dtimes = c("2002-06-09 12:45:40","2003-01-29 09:30:40",
+            "2002-09-04 16:45:40","2002-11-13 20:00:40",
+            "2002-07-07 17:30:40")
> dtparts = t(as.data.frame(strsplit(dtimes,' ')))
> row.names(dtparts) = NULL
> thetimes = chron(dates=dtparts[,1],times=dtparts[,2],
+                  format=c('y-m-d','h:m:s'))
> thetimes
[1] (02-06-09 12:45:40) (03-01-29 09:30:40) (02-09-04 16:45:40)
[4] (02-11-13 20:00:40) (02-07-07 17:30:40)
```

Please see this [link](https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-dates-times)

Answer (score 1):

Use function `hms` in package `lubridate`.

```
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date(hello, format = "%Y-%d-%m"))
df$time <- lubridate::hms(sub("^[^ ]*\\b(.*)$", "\\1", hello))

df
#         day       time
#1 2020-02-25 17H 42M 3S

str(df)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ day : Date, format: "2020-02-25"
# $ time:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#  .. ..@ .Data : num 3
#  .. ..@ year  : num 0
#  .. ..@ month : num 0
#  .. ..@ day   : num 0
#  .. ..@ hour  : num 17
#  .. ..@ minute: num 42
```

Comment: Thank you ! But when I have a date ("2021-16-01 00:05:40"), then the df$time is "5M 40S", and later in my algorithm it becomes an error...

Comment: @Emeline Check the condition `nchar(as.character(df$time)) <= 7` and act according to the result.

Comment: @Emeline Another way is to check `df$time@hour`. If it is zero, have your algorithm branch to treat that case.